# Password hash program

Tags: python, hash

I need to create a program that will allow the user to enter a pin number without revealing what the pin number actually is. Here is some more detail:

I will need to store inside the program a PIN number which the user should know before hand. Then I will need to generate a string of ten random numbers in the range 0 to 3. When the program runs it should print two lines like

```
PIN:   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9                    
       | | | | | | | | | |
       v v v v v v v v v v 
NUM:   2 2 3 1 1 1 3 2 3 2
```

If the user's PIN was "7724" they would type "2231".  The program will check to see if the digits 2231 indeed possibly correspond to 7724. If so, it should welcome the user into the program (and quits). If not, the user gets a warning and a grant total of three tries.

Notice that the initial "2" means the first digit of my PIN is 0 or 1 or 7 or 9.

I am new to python and am using 3.1
I'm not sure how to even start this code. Any help would be very appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: "Hello World" and input tutorials should be a good place to start.  Then find out how to import libraries, and grab md5 or sha and simply call them.

Comment: Note that your arrows show `0 <--> 2`. In fact, `0 --> 2` is true, but not `0 <-- 2`. - Optimally, that is always the case with hash functions. Further, the schema presented here isn't very secure, but you probably know that `:)`

Comment: Have you considered that since there's only 81 combinations of a 4-digit trinary number, the chance of guessing the right password by typing e.g. 1111 each time is 1 in 20, with 4 tries? (first failure plus three tries after warning, right?) That's a bit on the low side if it protects anything remotely important.

Comment: yes i have considered that. this is a homework assignment for class. I am stressing out over it and do not know where to start. if someone could just write a snippet of the code i can learn it from there. thank you again for any help at all. i do appreciate it.

Comment: use more than 3 digits in `NUM`, shouldnt make things any harder.  just use all 10 digits

Comment: Also, let's assume someone could observe the person typing the converted PIN (using a keyboard logger or a camera perhaps). Then if they could do 2-3 recordings of the same person logging in, it's very likely they could reconstruct his real pin. For each digit: first login it could be 0, 1, 7 or 9, second login: 2, 4, 7 or 8. So it's a 7. So if the purpose of this authentication method is to make it unnecessary to hide what you type, it fails at it.

Comment: @Arash Memarzadeh: Please use the [homework] tag for your homework.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a dictionary would be a good way to do this.  I'm trying to get you started, but please read both of these.

http://docs.python.org/library/random.html
http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

And the python tutorial in general: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/index.html

```
import random
pinToCode = dict()
for i in range(10):
   pintoCode(i) = random.randint(0,9)
```

That will set up the mapping you describe above.  I dont know how you are storing the pin, but you want to feed the user input and the correct pin's `pinToCode` mapping into a hash function and hope they match.

Don't use the function simply called `hash` it has no cryptographic value, its just for data structure implementation.

you can get started with hash functions here http://docs.python.org/library/crypto.html
http://docs.python.org/library/md5.html

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use a dict to map the digits to a random number from 1 to 3, inclusive:

```
from random import randint
dmap = {str(x): str(randint(1, 3)) for x in range(10)}  # 2.7+
```

Your question seems to indicate that the important thing is that the user should not reveal his PIN by typing it, and that how you store it in the program is unimportant. Therefore I assume you've got it stored as a plain string `pw = "7724"`.

For typing the map:

```
print(" ".join(sorted(dmap.keys())))
print(" ".join("|" for x in dmap.keys()))
print(" ".join("v" for x in dmap.keys()))
print(" ".join(map[x] for x in sorted(dmap.keys())))
```

Finally to verify:

```
correct = [dmap[x] for x in pw]
for i in range(4):
    if [dmap[x] for x in raw_input("Code:  ")] == correct:
        break
    print("Try again")
else:
    # Only run if for loop did not break
    print("Sorry, no more tries!")
    import sys
    sys.exit()
print("Correct!")
```